# sorted array in java using swap methods

Tags: java, arrays, loops, sorting

My problem is when I sort a list it will get the last element of the array wrong, ending up with it at the beginning of the array. In my example it fails to sort the last element which is 9, ending up printed first ahead of small numbers such as 0 and 1. Here is my code:

```
public class ty {
public static void main(String[]argus){
    int []numbers={45,23,34,545,56,23,4,1,66,0,9};  
    int j;
        for( int i=0;i<numbers.length;i+=1){
            int first=0;
            for(j=0;j<=i;j+=1){
                if(numbers[j]>=first){
                    first=numbers[j];
                    numbers[j]=numbers[i];
                    numbers[i]=first;}
            }//inner loop
        }//first loop
        for(int i=0;i<numbers.length;i+=1){
            System.out.print(numbers[i]+" ");}  
}
}
```

> **//the output is    9 0 1 4 23 23 34 45 56 66 545**

As you see, they are in order except for the 9 at the start which is out of place.

Comment: Don't use `first` as your swap variable: allocate a new variable, e.g. `int tmp = numbers[j];`.

Comment: you start with `first = 0` allways. Make it `first = numbers[i]`

Comment: public static void main(String[] **argus**). Argus is funny, I'm going to use it more often.

Comment: thanks for both of you i tried kevin Esche suggestion and worked perfectly thanks again appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong output as a result of a `logical error`. You have mistakes in the `Selection sort` technique. Here's how to do it:

```
int []numbers={45,23,34,545,56,23,4,1,66,0,9};

for(int i=0; i<numbers.length-1; i+=1){
    int m = i;
    for(int j=i+1; j<numbers.length; j+=1){
        if(numbers[m]>numbers[j])
            m = j;
    }
    int temp = numbers[m];
    numbers[m] = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = temp;
}

for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i+=1)
    System.out.print(numbers[i]+"\t");
```

This will work correctly and give the output:

> **0 1 4 9 23 23 34 45 56 66 545**